# How can I annotate a deleted file in git?

Tags: git, annotate

I want to annotate/blame a file in a git repository on a revision using the following command:

```
git annotate [options] file [revision]
```

However, the file does not exist in the current repository anymore, but I know that the file was exist in revision f80133a.

```
git annotate java/org/apache/catalina/valves/CometConnectionManagerValve.java f80133a
fatal: cannot stat path 'java/org/apache/catalina/valves/CometConnectionManagerValve.java': No such file or directory
```

Is there simple way to annotate a deleted file without checking out the revision f80133a in this situation?

Comment: Out of curiosity – why?

Comment: Actually, I am tracing all the source files ever existed in the repository. revision f80133a fixed a bug of the file, and I want to know the author and the change. There are more similar cases, and I want to make it automatically. @MattBall

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git stash                # if you have pending changes
git checkout f80133a
git annotate java/org/apache/catalina/valves/CometConnectionManagerValve.java > annotation.txt
git checkout master      # or develop, or wherever you were
git stash pop            # if stashed
```

EDIT after OP's edit: without checking out, I don't think so, but I may be wrong.

EDIT2: I am wrong. You can also trick git:

```
touch java/org/apache/catalina/valves/CometConnectionManagerValve.java
git annotate java/org/apache/catalina/valves/CometConnectionManagerValve.java f80133a
rm java/org/apache/catalina/valves/CometConnectionManagerValve.java
```

Comment: Thanks!! Amadan. Because I have too many this cases, checking out the revision for each case will be too costly. However, this will be my last solution. I am just wondering if there is any better ways. Thanks !!

Comment: Really? Is your EDIT2 works? I will try, that's interesting!

Comment: OMG! It really works!! This is really smart :-). Thanks Amadan.

Answer (score 0):

for the instance you can checkout to that commit to see the blame like

```
git checkout f80133a
```

after this you will reach that commit in a detached head state
then do blame

```
git annotate [options] file
```

and once you are done

```
git checkout your_prev_branch_name
```

Comment: Yes, this is a solution. However, I want to trace back all the files in the repository, this might too costly. If there is no better solution, I think I will adopt this one. Thanks !

Comment: in that case you can use some gui tool after doing checkout on ref